# JCR framework basic information

Tags: java, jcr

We are in a process to replace the current content management system with a new one that uses JCR Framework. I am new to java JCR API and in dire need to learn it as quickly as possible !!

Would some of the ignited minds here mind to extend a little help with the best online tutorials for a newbie ??

Any help will be appreciated. Mostly needed is information on how to start using it in a simple java/Java EE project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the basic, neat and quick information on the below links. Hope it helps someone else too

http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-content-repository-best

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/10/04/what-is-java-content-repository.html

http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/1.0/6.2.10_Example.html